# python pool.map_async doesn't wait for .wait()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to run a fat function which worked pretty well with pool.apply_async

Now, I'm trying out the pool.map_async function (with 2 arguments passed with the functools.partial method) and the program finishes immediately without any error or exceptions...

```
    files = list_files(mypath) # list of files to process
    csv_rows = None
    result = mp.Queue() #result queue from multiprocessing module

    pool = mp.Pool(4)
    t = pool.map_async( partial(process_file, result), files)
    t.wait() # it doesn't wait HERE ... program exits immediately - no errors
```

Any clues on what I might be missing?

Comment: Show us `process_file`. Also if you're just going to wait immediately you might as well use `pool.map()` instead.

Comment: You probably do have an error in `process_file` somewhere, but you won't see the exception in the main process until you call `get` on `t`.

Comment: @Blckknght can you show me an example for get? I'm new to the multiprocessing library ,,,

Comment: @AlexHall does the blocking part of map means that I'll wait till all 1000+ processes are finished? even when I know all of them are embarrassingly parallel?

Comment: Also, process file is way to large to paste here... It works seamlessly with .apply_async and .map as well

Comment: Just try `t.get()`. It's documented (alongside the `wait` method you're already calling) [right here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you probably don't need `map_async` if you are going to immediately `wait` on it.  If that is the case, then just use `map`.  You can potentially also remove your `queue` and just return the values.  But that's probably not the problem you are having.

The problem is likely that the `wait` method *doesn't raise remote exceptions*.  It is likely that your `process_file` method is actually failing in the pool processes but that you aren't seeing those exceptions.  Like **Blckknght** mentioned, you should switch to using a `get` method which, as you can see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult), will raise the remote exception.  Here is a simple example where the `wait` method hides the remote process exceptions and how if you switch to `get` you can see them again:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def just_dies(n):
    raise ValueError("Test")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = mp.Pool(4)
    results = pool.map_async(just_dies, range(10))

    # the wait will immediately silently pass
    #results.wait()

    # this will actually raise the remote exception
    results.get()
```

If you run this you will get a traceback error message like so

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 14, in <module>
    results.get()
  File "XXX/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
ValueError: Test
```

If you switch to using the `wait` method then you won't see it.